# Move CTabItem from one CTabFolder to another CTabFolder

Tags: java, swt

is there a way to move a CTabItem from one CTabFolder to another in SWT?

```
CTabFolder folder1 = new CTabFolder(parent, SWT.BORDER);
CTabFolder folder2 = new CTabFolder(parent, SWT.BORDER);

CTabItem tab = new CTabItem(folder1, SWT.BORDER);

// move tab from folder1 to folder2
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. `CTabItem` belongs to the original `CTabFolder` until it is disposed.

Objects derived from `Item` generally don't support changing the parent (objects derived from `Control` do have a `setParent` method).

Comment: Just to add something here in case this issue is still open. Items cannot move, but their contents (which are controls) can : just make sure that the contents of each of your items is a composite C1 that you create yourself, add all the contents you need as a composite C2 containing your actual controls. Now all you have to do when you detect a drag is : create a new item in the second folder, add a C1' to it, reparent C2 to C1', ask C1' to request a layout it in case the sizes do not match, destroy your previous item.